# What can I do to fix this issue of compiler not working for C in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, mingw

This is my first time using VsCode. I added the path, tried reinstalling the compiler.Nothing worked so far.

[image]

Comment: in the terminal `type` or `cat` or `more` the file you want to compile, then you see what the compiler sees

Answer (score 2):

Before you compile and execute your code, you need to SAVE it first. I see that you have a little round circle at the top, and a (1) on the left hand side. This means you have not saved the code.

What you do is hit Ctrl+S, then compile the code, then execute it. This should fix your issue.